# iOS Visual Effect View with Blur not transparent while testing on iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, transparent, uivisualeffectview

I have a problem with Visual Effect View with Blur. 
I have a ViewController where I add a subView. subView's background is Clear Color. And on the SubView I have a Visual Effect View with Blur with some UIElements on it.

While I tested it in the Simulator on mac, everything with OK, but I've tried to launch this app on my Phone (iPhone 5S) and there is no blur, but only darkGrey backGround.
But when I try to make a screenShot on my phone, it is made with transparent blurred background.

[image]

Comment: Did you activated advanced visual effects on your iphone ?

Comment: @David'mArm'Ansermot do you mean to turn off "Reduce screen motion" or something else? It's turned off. S everything should be fine.

Comment: Yep this is what i meant

Comment: `Reduce Motion` is irrelevant. How about `Reduce Transparency`? It's under `Increase Contrast`